# how to access spinner inside different layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner, android-inflate

I've been trying to solve a problem which i been having for past week , i am trying to a access spinner inside different xml layout, all i want is to access the spinner and add array to the spinner.

This is the code i am using and it doesn't work

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainreg);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
View view123 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.one2reg, mainLayout,false);

Spinner spin = (Spinner) view123.findViewById(R.id.spinnerproblem);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);    

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
mainLayout.addView(view123);
```

Comment: the problem is i cant access the spinner so i can add "item" array also i can add setOnItemSelectedListener to the spinner . the only problem i could think of is just i cant access the spinner .

Comment: What kind of exception do you see in Logcat? Also it's not clear what's the point of adding a spinner the way you do, why not declare it in your mainreg xml file as child of main_layout_id?

Comment: i want to do it this way is because i got fragment layout which is linked to three different xml layouts. so in my main class i make the fragments so i can slide throw the pages . now i am facing this problem because the spinner is in different xml layout. many thanks Anton

Comment: you should probably utilize the <include> layout trick instead of messing with controls management in code. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for details

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass true for attach to root while inflating layout, like this.

```
View view123 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.one2reg, mainLayout,true);
```

Comment: 08-16 13:54:35.535: E/AndroidRuntime(9264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{police.app/police.app.MainReg}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-16 13:54:35.535: E/AndroidRuntime(9264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
08-16 13:54:35.535: E/AndroidRuntime(9264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
..........

Comment: Sorry.. i think you should remove the following line. mainLayout.addView(view123);